# How to disable window edge tiling and enable window edge resistance in Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I just installed an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS under FreeNAS/bhyve, and I can't disable the window maximising when hitting the upper edge of the screen. Window edge resistance also seems to be missing.

I've successfully set these with gnome-tweaks and/or dconf in my earlier installations, but now they don't have any effect. In dconf I've set org.gnome.shell.overrides.edge-tiling and org.gnome.mutter.edge-tiling to false, and disabled edge-tiling in gnome-tweaks, but windows that hit the upper edge are still maximised.

Also, my earlier installations had window edge resistance when moving, and I could shift-move the windows so that they'd always stick to one another, but no more.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 21.04 under xorg. For me, edge tiling (on dragging the window to the edges) is effectively disabled disabling these two keys (actually just the `mutter` key is enough).

Comment: It only seems to affect gnome-terminal; browser and other programs have proper edge resistance and don't maximise.

Comment: For me, `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false` in Ubuntu 20.04, GTK 3.24.20 disabled edge tiling on gnome-terminal as well.

Comment: nothing works. nor the tweaks app nor the terminal command. Edge tiling is still on. Even after multiple restarts. I am using RTX A5000.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to the beta of Noble and I find that this can be done by going Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop, scrolling down and turning off Enhanced Tiling. I now have edge resistance but no tiling, which is good! Not sure if this is new or if I just overlooked it on earlier versions.